# JQuery Select2 Plugin + Laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, jquery-select2, laravel-5.3

I Have some problem while using Select2 Jquery Plugin cause its my 1st time use it.

```
    $(".select-class").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "{{route('route-next')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
                type: 'type_of_mine',
                kelas : kelas,
                jurusan : jurusan,
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data.results };
        }

    },
    initSelection: function (item, callback) {
        var id = item.val();
        var text = item.data('option');
        if(id > 0){
            var data = { id: id, text: text };
            callback(data);
        }
    },
    formatAjaxError:function(a,b,c){return"Not Found .."}
});
```

but i always got this error message on my console :

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/initSelection(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, `initSelection` has been removed in later versions of Select2.

You can find more information about it's removal and how to fix it [here](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection).

Hope that helps!